# Should Flux.then and Mono.then behave differently in error case?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I encountered a case where I have a nested Flux. I don't care about the individual results of the inner flux as it returns Unit (in Kotlin / Void in Java), but I want to know if the Flux aborted due to an error or not. I thought I could use the `then` function, as the doc states: `Error signal is replayed in the resulting Mono<V>`

My problem can be reduced to the minimum (Kotlin) unit test:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun fluxTest() {
        val flux = Flux.just("willFail", "willSucceed")
            .flatMap { outer ->
                // In my real world example the inner flux is created via Flux.fromIterable from a property of the
                // outer`-object
                Flux.just(1)
                    .flatMap { inner ->
                        // this simulates a Mono.fromSupplier that can throw exceptions
                        if (outer == "willFail") Mono.error<Unit>(RuntimeException("bam"))
                        else Mono.just(Unit)
                    }
                    // We don't care about the Flux as it returns Unit/Void
                    // All we want to know is, whether there was an error or not
                    .then(Mono.just(outer))
            }
            .onErrorContinue { error, item -> println("$item => $error") }
            .collectList()

        StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectNextMatches { it.size == 1 }
            .verifyComplete()
    }
```

So we have 2 elements. In the inner Flux one of the elements will fail on processing and the other won't. I expect the error to propagate through the pipeline where it is catched and discarded in the `onErrorContinue`.
Therefore I'd expect 1 element in the resulting list, but I get the original 2. I have no clue why.

Now comes the fun part: In this particular test case, I can replace `Flux.just(1)` with `Mono.just(1)` (in my real world case this doesn't work ofc because the flux has more than 1 element) and suddenly my test passes:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun fluxTest() {
        val flux = Flux.just("willFail", "willSucceed")
            .flatMap { outer ->
                // In my real world example the inner flux is created via Flux.fromIterable from a property of the
                // outer`-object
                Mono.just(1)
                    .flatMap { inner ->
                        // this simulates a Mono.fromSupplier that can throw exceptions
                        if (outer == "willFail") Mono.error<Unit>(RuntimeException("bam"))
                        else Mono.just(Unit)
                    }
                    // We don't care about the Flux as it returns Unit/Void
                    // All we want to know is, whether there was an error or not
                    .then(Mono.just(outer))
            }
            .onErrorContinue { error, item -> println("$item => $error") }
            .collectList()

        StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectNextMatches { it.size == 1 }
            .verifyComplete()
    }
```

So obviously there is a difference in `Mono.then(Mono<T>)` and in `Flux.then(Mono<T>)`, but it shouldn't since the Javadoc is the same right?

Side note: Instead of `Flux.then(Mono.just(outer))` I also tried `Mono.defer` but that is not changing anything.

Comment: This is strange. By browsing project issues, I've found [this one](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2184) that might be related to your problem. Apparently there's hidden complexity about `onErrorContinue` that could cause unexpected behaviours.